# Find a recurrence relation for $a_m =\frac{2m+1}{2^{m+1}m!}\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^me^x dx $.

Tags: definite-integrals, recurrence-relations

My task is to find a recurrence relation for the following definite intergral:
$$a_m =\frac{2m+1}{2^{m+1}m!}\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^me^x dx $$ using only $a_{m-1}$ and $a_{m-2}$. I found the first two terms:
$$a_0 = \frac{1}{2}(e^1-e^{-1})$$
$$a_1 = 3e^{-1}$$
My attempt at a recurrence relation goes like this. For $a_{m-1}$ and $a_{m-2}$, we have that by definition
$$ a_{m-2} =\frac{2m-3}{2^{m-1}(m-2)!}\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)e^x dx$$
$$ a_{m-1} =\frac{2m-1}{2^{m+1}(m-1)!}\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^{m-1}e^x dx$$
If we use integration by part on $a_m$, we get
$$a_m =\frac{2m+1}{2^{m+1}m!} \{e^x(1-x^2)^m \Big|_{-1}^1 + 2m \int_{-1}^{1}  e^x x(1-x^2)^{m-1}  \} $$
I know that the first term is clearly 0, so we are left with

$$a_m =\frac{2m+1}{2^{m}(m-1)!}  \int_{-1}^{1}  e^x x(1-x^2)^{m-1}   $$

If we do by parts again, the same way, the first term is again 0 and is

$$a_m =\frac{2m+1}{2^{m}(m-1)!} \{ -\int_{-1}^{1}  e^x \Big( (1-x^2)^{m-1} - 2 (m-1)x^2(1-x^2)^{m-2} \Big)  \} $$
We can finally use one of the previous terms and $a_m$ becomes

$$a_m = -\frac{2m+1}{2m-1} a_{m-1}+ \frac{2m+1}{2^{m-1}(m-2)!}    \int_{-1}^{1}  e^x x^2 (1-x^2)^{m-2} \}$$
Which is where I get stuck. I can't seem to get rid of that pesky $x^2$.
Any hints would be appreciated, or perhaps a different approach to the problem altogether. Thank you!

Comment: $x^2=1-(1-x^2)$, which you should use in the line before that in the $\dots-2(m-1)x^2(1-x^2)^{m-2}$.

Comment: Genius. Thank you good sir.